# Использование return без возвращаемого значения

Tags: java, методы, return

Есть код:

```
private void showResult() {
        if (mt == null) return;
        int result = -1;
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Try to get result");
            result = mt.get();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "get returns " + result);
            Toast.makeText(this, "get returns " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Почему `return` прописывается без возвращаемого значения и что при этом происходит?

Comment: Завершение работы функции

Comment: Не могли бы вы развить ваш вопрос, потому что код не имеет смысла и не понятно что вы имели ввиду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, ключевое слово return использовано для того, чтобы **прервать** дальнейшее выполнение метода **и вернуть управление** обратно вызывающему методу.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку у Вас функция `showResult` объявлена как `void`? то есть не возращяет значения.

> Оператор `return` используется для выполнения явного возврата из метода.
> То есть он снова передает управление объекту, который вызвал данный
> метод. ... Оператор `return` предписывает интерпретатору Java остановить
> выполнение текущего метода. Если метод возвращает значение, оператор
> `return` сопровождается некоторым выражением.

в Вашем случае просто выполнения явного возврата из метода.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showResult() {
        if (mt == null) return; //Если mt == null функция здесь завершается
        int result = -1;
        try {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Try to get result");
            result = mt.get();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "get returns " + result);
            Toast.makeText(this, "get returns " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> Почему return прописывается без возвращаемого значения

Так как у вас  функция типа void, функция ничего не должен возвращать.